# Splitting pgfplottable accross two columns

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, longtable, pgfplotstable, columns

I have a long table in my appendix with lots of data that I want to split not just over many pages but into two columns (i.e. two tables side by side to take up fewer sides). Is this possible?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Applications of the Kalman Filter to Timeseries Analysis}
\author{Freddie Poser \& Andr\'e Renom}
\date{2017}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}


\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    fixed,precision=2,
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable}
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotstableread{results.dat}\datatable

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\definecolor{code-green}{HTML}{29d875}
\definecolor{code-blue}{HTML}{297bd8}

\def\code#1{\texttt{#1}}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[2]\itshape,
    keywordstyle=[3],
    stringstyle=\itshape,
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
    showstringspaces=false
}

\lstdefinelanguage{Scala}{  
    keywords=[2]{List, DenseVector},
    keywords=[3]{that, DELTA\_TIME},
    morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,
        do,else,extends,false,final,finally,
        for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,
        new,null,object,override,package, 
        private,protected,requires,return,sealed,
        super,this,trait,true,try,
        type,val,var,while,with,yield,Double},
    sensitive,
    morecomment=[l]//,
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]""",
}


\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/SNAME/.style={
        string type
    },
    every head row/.style={
        output empty row
    },
    every first row/.style={before row={% <=================================
            \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
            \label{tab:DataTable}\\
            \toprule 
            Stock Index & Stock Name & $P_{kalman}$ & $P_{sma}$ & $P_{wma}$ \\ 
            \toprule    
            \endfirsthead % <=======================================================
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
            \toprule
            Stock Index & Stock Name & $P_{kalman}$ & $P_{sma}$ & $P_{wma}$ \\ 
            \midrule
            \endhead % <============================================================
            \midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
            \endfoot % <============================================================
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{5}{r}{{End of table}} \\ \bottomrule
            \endlastfoot % <========================================================
    }}%
    ]{\datatable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. This will help us help us!

Comment: @ebo Have done!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works for me. Instead of trying to split the table over two columns I used the `select equal part entry of` key to split the data over two matching sets of columns. It looks like this:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={S,SNAME,KAL,SMA,WMA,S,SNAME,KAL,SMA,WMA},
    display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}, column name=$i$},
    display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},string type, column name={Stock}},
    display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}, column name=$P_{kalman}$},
    display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}, column name=$P_{SMA}$},
    display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}, column name=$P_{WMA}$},
    display columns/5/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}, column name=$i$},
    display columns/6/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},string type, column name={Stock}},
    display columns/7/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}, column name=$i$}
    display columns/8/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}, column name=$P_{SMA}$},
    display columns/9/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}, column name=$P_{WMA}$},
    every head row/.style={before row=\caption{Full experimental data}\label{tab:data}\\\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead}
    ]{\datatable}
```